# How many GB RAM do I buy for Android Studio?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-emulator, augmented-reality

I am currently learning android development. Then I will improve myself in the AR field. I have a project in my mind in AR + Android + Machine Learning areas. I will develop myself step by step for this project.

I think I'm going to upgrade the laptops that I am currently using. Android Studio and Emulator do not open together on the laptop. Ram is not enough. I can also use my own physical device in tests. But when I open Android Studio + Chrome on my side, 4 GB Ram will not suffice. Are you 8 GB or 16 GB? Laptops have only one ram slot. What should be the most logical choice for you?

In Turkey, 8GB Ram is 400 TL and 16GB Ram is 800 TL. You should think that 8GB Ram is 400 unit price. Also, the minimum job price is 1600TL, You should think that is 1600 unit price.

1. Notebook: Lenovo Yoga 510 - 14ISK

   - Intel Core i5-6200U, 3M Cache, 2.3GHz, Turbo Boost 2.8GHz
   - 4 GB DDR4 2133 MHz Ram
   - 2 GB AMD Radeon R5 M430 Graphic Card
   - 500 GB HDD (8 GB SSD, hybrid)
   - 14 "1920x1080 IPS Screen
2. I have also Desktop:

   - Intel Core i5-3570, 6M Cache, 3.4GHz, Turbo Boost 3.8GHz
   - 8 GB DDR3 1600 MHz Ram
   - 4 GB AMD Radeon RX560 Graphic Card, GDDR5, 128 Bit
   - 500 GB HDD
3. Here are some ram usage on the desktop:

   - Android Studio -> 4.5 GB
   - Android Studio + Emulator -> 6.5GB
   - Android Studio + Chrome (10 Tabs) -> 5.6GB
   - Android Studio + Emulator + Chrome (10 Tabs) -> 7.3GB

Comment: https://helponnet.com/2021/04/11/does-android-studio-work-on-4-8gb-ram/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use Emulator  .. you can use Genymotion with Oracle VM VirtualBox

Comment: Do I have to pay for Genymotion?

Comment: you can create free account and use it freely.

Answer (score 5):

According to your own observation:

> Android Studio -> 4.5 GB

So 4GB laptop is totally a NO, 8GB minimum is what I will recommended and then again I would be more worried of that low power dual core CPU of the Yoga 510 then the amount of RAM. RAM can be upgraded for many laptops but those Intel U series CPUs are power saving not for heavy task that you wish. I would suggest you to stick with your desktop.

Answer (score 4):

I have a laptop with 12 Gb of ram, but the emulator make the laptop so hot! 
Use your own phone with debug activated.
Go on settings, phone info and tap 7 times on your build number, it activates the developer option, open developer option and activate debug USB, connect the phone to the pc and run it on your phone ☺️

Comment: Yes, you are right about this. But only the android studio and chrome can sometimes lag. What do you think, sould I buy 8gb or 16gb ?

Comment: The minimum are 4gb, without emulator, suggested are 8 for android studio + 1 for emulator so a total of 9 Gb suggested with emulator, so you need a 16gb Ram, 8 isn't enough.

Comment: Well I am on react-native and experiencing usual crashes and I do have this machine: Lenovo Legion Y520-15IKBN Gaming 15.6" Full HD IPS, Core i5-7300HQ, 16GB, 1TB+128GB SSD, GTX 1050 Ti 4G. Funny things I though it was due the fact that as Ubuntu does not play well with the Nvidia I disabled the GPU. So then I enabled it again and fixed the issue. Still once I rebuil, all the OS randomly got stack. I also tried with real device. That does not make thing much better.